# Backbone fetching data using a callback cursor

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, recursion

How would I use Backbones fetch to deal with callback results that contain a cursor? I'm going to use this simple example of a book that is fetching pages.

```
var Book = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Page,

    recursiveFetch: function(cursor) {
        this.fetch({
            url: 'book/pages',
            data: {
                cursor: {cursor here};
            },
            success: function(response) {
               if (response.cursor) {
                   this.recursiveFetch(response.cursor);
               }
            }
        });
    }
})
```

I need to be able to use fetch to keep fetching until the response doesn't contain a cursor. It should keep adding page models, but not replacing and overwriting them. It needs to do something like the example above, though I'm not sure of the best way to implement it.

Comment: Do you mean collection will fetch pages from url book/pages multiple times until response don't contain cursor? Or collection will only request just one time and you have to check pages and add page to collection until it don't contain cursor?

Comment: It'll keep keep fetching until the response doesn't contain a cursor. I ended up handing by using this in the parse method `if (!data.cursor) this.unset('cursor');` The idea being to not let it call catch again if the cursor isn't set on the object.

Comment: @Josh I guess the question is already long forgotten, but I just came over it while hacking the vocab-editor and I have a solution. Should I post the answer?

Comment: @laughedelic It's funny that you ran into this post. I think we've also come up with some more clever ways of handling it as well. But feel free to post your solution for other that might stumble upon it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that all you need to do is add in a `{remove: false}`  into your fetch options. Its also worth mentioning that the `this` context of your success function may not be the collection, so you might want to pass it into the success function as a parameter. The end result would be:

```
recursiveFetch: function(cursor) {
    this.fetch({
        remove:false, // prevents removal of existing models
        url: 'book/pages',
        success: function(collection, response) {
           if (response.cursor) {
               collection.recursiveFetch(response.cursor);
           }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried adding in the `remove:false` bit and it would move on to the second cursor. After that it would do an infinite loop while calling the same cursor.

Comment: I'd need to know more about your cursor to help further. Often there is another parameter that says you are at the last page, which is separate to the parameter that tells you the page to retrieve next. but that's all speculation at the moment sorry.

Comment: No, there is no other parameter for determining the last page. If there is a cursor there is more data, if there isn't then it should stop fetching. The cursor appears looks something like 12910298.134 and will increment while passing it back as a fetch parameter.

Comment: Just a quick question, what are you doing with the `cursor` parameter? its passed in, but doesn't appear to be used all. Don't you need to pass it as a URL query parameter?

Comment: You're right. I updated my example to pass data including the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is very simple: add cursor to the parameters only when it's present. In other cases (i.e. the first time) make a normal request with the rest of the parameters.

```
var CursorCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  fetchAll: function(cursor) {

    var params = {
      // if you have some other request parameters...
    };

    // if we have a cursor from the previous call, add it to the parameters
    if (cursor) { params.cursor = cursor; }

    this.fetch({
      remove: false,
      data: params,
      success: function(collection, response) {
        if (response.cursor) {
          return collection.fetchAll(response.cursor);
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Then the first time you call it `collection.fetchAll()` and it recurses until it gets a response without a cursor.

Note, that the `remove: false` parameter is very important to accumulate the results as pointed out by @dcarson.